# How to write a Core Data fetch request predicate to compare an NSNumber as a bitmap

Tags: ios, core-data, bitmap, nspredicate

I have a Core Data Entity attribute called 'type'. Its of type integer in core data, so a NSNumber when pulled out  and the value is a bitmap that I wish to filter on for a specific set of values

I've been trying to compose a NSPredicate for this along the lines of

```
NSPredicate *typeOfFacilityPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type AND %@ > %0",@6667, @0];
```

Xcode if giving me *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "type AND %@ > %@"'

Is it possible to perform this logic in a core data fetch predicate predicate ? Or do i have to to make a series of ORs where i compare the type to a number of different values ? or perhaps create an array of values and do something along the lines of ANY type IN

Any ideas on how to correctly write the predicate would be gratefully received.

Comment: Not at my Mac, so can't test, but try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bitwiseAnd:with:(type, %@) > %@",@6667, @0]`.  The documentation for this and similar functions is tucked away in the [NSExpression API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsexpression/1413747-init).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So having returned to my Mac I was able to check this and, indeed,

```
NSPredicate *typeOfFacilityPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bitwiseAnd:with:(type, %@) > %@",@6667, @0];
```

should work. But having checked the SQL generated by this, I see that a much simpler solution is just to replace "AND" in your predicate with "&":

```
NSPredicate *typeOfFacilityPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type & %@ > %@",@6667, @0];
```

Comment: Thanks pbasf, much appreciated